# Nested find method with opposite of found indices

Tags: matlab, find

another try as my [first][1] did not work out well. I want to filter a set of values `A` into subsets that do fit constraints. And after that filter these subset into more subsets with new constraints. And so one. Problem is I don't want to use `find` more than once on the whole set `A`. And only 1 time on the subset.

- **AND**due to the fact that my matrices T B etc can be up to 600x600 i dont want to search twice with find():

  - indices=find(T=.....)
  - T(indices)=...
  - T(~indices)=...

i want:

```
Input:       A=[100 200 300; 400 500, 1000; -150000, -300000 -2]
   -  B=[3 3 3; 2 2 2; -1e9 -1e8 -1]


         - First Step:      A(indices)=find(A<20000 and B >= 2]
         - A(indices)=[100 200 300; 400 500; 1000]
         - A(~indices)=[-150000, -300000, -2]
 - B(~indices)=[-1e9 -1e8 -1]



  - Second Step:      

     - indices_2=find(B(~indices)>-130000)
     - A(~indices(indices_2))=[desired value]
```

But i cant use logic because A(~indices) gives me the values and not the position without find.   I want to use find() one time per set i split. Not twice.

Comment: Consider posting sample input and expected output. If possible, also try to explain the requirements using the sample data.

Comment: Also perhaps list all the constraints in the order you intend to apply them. I still don't see why logical indexing doesn't solve your problem alone without using `find` at all...

Comment: Your first `A(indices)<9` would never happen because `A(indices)` is always greater than `19` by construction. So it would be better if you explained what you are expecting to see as the result using a small numerical example as Divakar has suggested. *EDIT* your question to add sample input data and manually calculated sample output data

Comment: @kybnation Can't read that, please edit and use the code tags properly (not bullet points!), Also it doen't look like you've provided sample input or output data...

Comment: Use [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) on the found indices with `1:numel(T)`.

Comment: @Dan once again edited. Iput and output.  :D  I hope this does it for you :(

Comment: `setdiff` did increase the performance by up to 1e4 percent because it sorts the indices before evaluating.